# android SQLite database java.lang.IllegalStateException?

Tags: android

Hi i am using SQlite database for my app.
and i want to retrieve max value of increment primary key i.e ROWID.
but when i write query for this i got this exception

```
   10-21 11:02:50.062: D/IllegalStateException(2575): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field             slot from row 0 col -1 failed
```

my method for retrieving max value is

```
  public String getMaxID(){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  String productName = SingleTonClass.getInstance().dummy_productname;
  String QUERY = "SELECT max("+ROW_ID+") as ID FROM "+TABLE_NAME
        +" where "+PRODUCT_NAME+ " = " + "'" +productName+ "'";
    Log.d("Query for Get previous cost", ""+QUERY);
  Cursor maxID = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);

   String max = null;
   int temp = 1;
   try{

    while(maxID.moveToNext()){

        max = maxID.getString(maxID.getColumnIndex(ROW_ID));
        Log.d("MaxID", ""+max);
        maxID.close();


        }
     // }

     //      return max;
    }catch(IllegalStateException e){
    Log.d("IllegalStateException", ""+e);
   }finally{
    //      maxID.close();
    /       db.close();
    }

   return max;

   }
```

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here

```
max = maxID.getString(maxID.getColumnIndex(ROW_ID));
```

Change to this

```
max = maxID.getString(maxID.getColumnIndex("ID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get this column:

```
max = maxID.getString(maxID.getColumnIndex(ROW_ID));
```

But in your query you are using an alias:

```
"max("+ROW_ID+") as ID"
```

Try doing the following:

```
max = maxID.getString(maxID.getColumnIndex("ID")));
```

Hope it helps